# Question about showing sql server data in a tabbed view

Tags: c#, t-sql

I am creating a inventory app using c# that pulls its info from sql server. I am making it a tabbed view, with each tab representing a different type of item. I have included some of my code, what I am trying to figure is, is there a better way to do this? I dont feel like the way I am doing is right, even though it works. All my queries for each tab are stored procedures. Secondly, How would I insert and update the database through the grid?

```
 public partial class InventoryWindow : Window
{

    private InventoryDS InvDS;

    private String connString = "server=PC-server;database=Inventory;user=user;password=password";

    String sqlString_Routers = InventoryOutputQuery.InventorySummary_Routers();

    public InventoryWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (dgDataView != null)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString_Routers, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(ds, sqlString_Routers);
            dgDataView.DataContext = ds;
        }
    }

    private void showTaps()
    {
        String sqlString_Taps = InventoryOutputQuery.InventorySummary_Routers();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString_Routers, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        dgDataView.DataContext = dt;
        con.Close();
    }

    private void showPower()
    {
        String sqlString_Power = InventoryOutputQuery.InventorySummary_Power();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString_Power, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        dgDataView.DataContext = dt;
        con.Close();
    }

    private void showSwitches()
        {
            String sqlString_Switches = InventoryOutputQuery.InventorySummary_Switches();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString_Switches, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dgDataView.DataContext = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
```

And below is how i bind it to the grid:

```
public void BindGrid(string view)
{
    switch (view.ToUpper())
    {
        case "Routers":
            showTaps();
            break;
        case "POWER":
            showPower();
            break;
        case "SWITCHES":
            showSwitches();
            break;
        case "HUBS":
            showHubs();




private void tcDataView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabItem ti = tcDataView.SelectedItem as TabItem;

            if (ti != null)
                BindGrid(ti.Header.ToString());
        }
                    break;
```

Comment: To update your data you can use Update method from SqlDataAdapter. If your program is working and you are not using huge amounts of data it's ok. Otherwise you should think about memory usage. Of course it's not programming masterpiece, but that's not the point.

Comment: Thanks, so what I ant to do is create a new window where the user can put in all the information for a new item, as well as, update an item. Do you know of any tutorials that could help with that?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to be careful with how we handle SqlConnection. It is a scarce resource and it will run out pretty soon if we are not careful.
Please wrap sql code in a using block, for example:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString_Routers, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(ds, sqlString_Routers);
    dgDataView.DataContext = ds;
}
```

The following link will explain the effect of 'using' block in a bit more details.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tinguusingstatement.aspx